# Chrome remove titlebar through CLI

Tags: linux, chromium, fedora, gnome, kiosk-mode

Trying to setup a kiosk using gnome-kiosk-mode Wayland on Fedora 38 but when I run the kiosk script:

```
sleep 15s

if [ ! "\$(pidof eog)" ]; then
   /usr/bin/chromium-browser --force-device-scale-factor=2 --password-store=basic --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars  --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --kiosk http:localhost:8080 
fi

sleep 1.0
exec "\$0" "\$@"
```

Chrome opens up with this title bar that has the maximize, minimize, close button on it:

[image: Screenshot of the bar]

I know you can go into the Chrome settings > Appearance >  Use system title bar and borders and turn that off to disable it but the problem is I am trying to create a script that sets the whole kiosk up from the command line and this seems to be impossible to disable from the command line.

If anyone can provide some help on this I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Tried researching methods and documentation to flip this chrome setting off from the command line and was not able to find anything.

Comment: `--kiosk` should achieve exactly that - full-screen with no decorations, and we have several Raspberry Pis at work doing exactly that - displaying monitoring dashboards in kiosk-mode. Which makes me wonder whether it's Gnome being an arsehat.

Comment: @tink I am pretty certain it is gnome being an ass lol. Sometimes it wont even open in fullscreen using the --kiosk flag.